# Получение значения изображения из iframe

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
function Smail(){
    document.getElementById(textbox).contentWindow.document.execCommand("InsertImage", false, 'http://ффф.com/smaill/k20.gif');
}
```

Как получить значение этого изображения, чтобы отправить на сервер.

```
var text=$('#'+textbox).contents().find('body').html();
```

С помощью этого кода получаем слова из `iframe`, а изображение как получить?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, у вас уже есть body. С помощью jQuery найти все изображения не составит труда.